# ListView accessibility issue -- how to make Windows Narrator read the entire selected row, including subitems?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, accessibility, common-controls

I'm trying to add accessibility support to the [WC_LISTVIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298360(v=vs.85).aspx) control in my Win32/MFC application. I'm using [Windows Narrator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17173/windows-10-hear-text-read-aloud) tool in Windows 10 to test the results. And by default it only reads the main item name of a selected row. For instance, in this case:

[image]

it will read only the country, when I need it to read the whole line.

So I found that I can set up a [Server annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373681(v=vs.85).aspx) for the list-view control using [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373637(v=vs.85).aspx).

I would first set it up as such:

```
CAccPropServer_ListView* pMyPropSrv = NULL;
HRESULT hr;

CComPtr<IAccPropServices> pAccPropSvc = NULL;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AccPropServices, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_IAccPropServices, (void **)&pAccPropSvc);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr) &&
    pAccPropSvc )
{
    pMyPropSrv = new (std::nothrow) CAccPropServer_ListView( pAccPropSvc );
    if( pMyPropSrv )
    {

        MSAAPROPID propids[] = {
            PROPID_ACC_NAME,
        };

        hr = pAccPropSvc->SetHwndPropServer( hWndListCtrl, OBJID_CLIENT,
            CHILDID_SELF, propids, 1, pMyPropSrv, ANNO_CONTAINER);

        pMyPropSrv->Release();
    }
}
```

where the `CAccPropServer_ListView` class does all the work:

```
class CAccPropServer_ListView: public IAccPropServer
{
    ULONG               m_Ref;
    IAccPropServices *  m_pAccPropSvc;

public:

    CAccPropServer_ListView( IAccPropServices * pAccPropSvc )
        : m_Ref( 1 ),
          m_pAccPropSvc( pAccPropSvc )
    {
        m_pAccPropSvc->AddRef();
    }

    ~CAccPropServer_ListView()
    {
        m_pAccPropSvc->Release();
    }


    /* TODO: Addref/Release/QI go here...
           Skipped them for brevity...
     */


    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPropValue (const BYTE * pIDString,
        DWORD dwIDStringLen, MSAAPROPID idProp, VARIANT * pvarValue,
        BOOL * pfGotProp )
    {
        if(!pfGotProp)
            return E_POINTER;

        pvarValue->vt = VT_EMPTY;
        *pfGotProp = FALSE;

        HWND  hwnd;
        DWORD idObject;
        DWORD idChild;

        if( S_OK != m_pAccPropSvc->DecomposeHwndIdentityString( pIDString, 
                  dwIDStringLen, &hwnd, &idObject, &idChild ) )
        {
            return S_OK;
        }

        if( idChild != CHILDID_SELF )
        {
            if( idProp == PROPID_ACC_NAME )
            {
                CString str;
                str.Format(L"Line index %d", idChild);

                BSTR bstr = ::SysAllocString((LPCTSTR)str.GetString());
                pvarValue->vt = VT_BSTR;
                pvarValue->bstrVal = bstr;

                *pfGotProp = TRUE;
            }
        }

        return S_OK;
    }



};
```

So my question is concerning `GetPropValue` method above that actually generates the text prompt for Narrator to read out loud.

How do I get an index of a row read by the Narrator from the `idChild` that is returned by [DecomposeHwndIdentityString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318503(v=vs.85).aspx)?

In my example above, purely experimentally, I was getting the following values:

```
"Line index 17"
"Line index 33"
"Line index 49"
"Line index 65"
and so on
```

which would translate to `0x11`, `0x21`, `0x31`, `0x41` that are not row indexes. Are those IDs documented anywhere for a `SysListView32`?

Comment: What were the original `pIDString`s?